# Last item in ListView returns OutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview

I have an old app wherein there is also a delete button in every item in listview. I followed its format to use in my recent application but it gives me `OutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size 4` whenever I try to remove the last item in my listview.

the error occurs when:

- I try to delete the **last** item in the list

  - I try to delete the **only** item in the list

here is how I remove the item from my list:

Cart_Adapter:

```
   productHolder.item_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cart_list.remove(getItem(position));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
```

WHAT I TRIED BUT ALL FAILED:

- `remove(getItem(position));` with and without notifyDataSetChanged
- `remove(cart_list.get(position));`with and without notifyDataSetChanged
- `cart_list.remove(getItem(position));`
- `cart_list.remove(position);`

**EDIT**:
FULL ADAPTER CLASS

```
package dagger.com.japorms.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import dagger.com.japorms.R;

import dagger.com.japorms.fragment.Cart_Fragment;
import dagger.com.japorms.main.User_Activity;
import dagger.com.japorms.model.Cart_List;
import dagger.com.japorms.model.Cart_Model;
import dagger.com.japorms.model.Order;
import dagger.com.japorms.model.Pending_Items_Model;
import dagger.com.japorms.model.Product_List;
import dagger.com.japorms.other.HttpConstants;
import dagger.com.japorms.service.APIService;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static dagger.com.japorms.other.HttpConstants.BASE_URL;
import static dagger.com.japorms.other.HttpConstants.HTTP_PRODUCT_IMAGE;

/**
 * Created by Claude on 06/07/2017.
 */

public class Cart_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cart_List> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Cart_List> cart_list = new ArrayList<>();
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");

    int item_list;
    int temp;

    Double total_amount =0.00d;

    public Cart_Adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Cart_List> cart_list) {

        super(context,layoutResourceId,cart_list);

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.cart_list = cart_list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        ProductHolder productHolder;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);

            productHolder = new ProductHolder();
            productHolder.item_img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_img);
            productHolder.item_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_name);
            productHolder.item_price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_price);
            productHolder.item_qty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_qty);
            productHolder.item_size = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_size);
            productHolder.item_modify = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_modify);
            productHolder.item_delete = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cart_remove);


            row.setTag(productHolder);


        }
        else

            productHolder = (ProductHolder) row.getTag();


            productHolder.item_name.setText("Name: "+cart_list.get(position).getItemName());
            productHolder.item_price.setText("Price: PHP " + formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(cart_list.get(position).getItemPrice())));
            productHolder.item_qty.setText("Quantity: "+cart_list.get(position).getItemQty());
            productHolder.item_size.setText("Size: "+cart_list.get(position).getSize());

            Picasso.with(context).load(BASE_URL + HTTP_PRODUCT_IMAGE + cart_list.get(position).getCategory() + "/" +
                    cart_list.get(position).getItemId() + ".jpg").into(productHolder.item_img);





        productHolder.item_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                cart_list.remove(getItem(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(HttpConstants.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);


                Call<Pending_Items_Model> call = service.deletePendingItem( cart_list.get(position).getItemId());

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Pending_Items_Model>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Pending_Items_Model> call, Response<Pending_Items_Model> response) {
                        ((User_Activity) context).CheckCart();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Pending_Items_Model> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });


        return row;



    }





    static class ProductHolder{

        ImageView item_img;
        TextView item_name;
        TextView item_price;
        TextView item_qty;
        TextView item_size;
        TextView item_modify;
        TextView item_delete;
    }
}
```

Comment: your position (what ever it is) is of by one, so if you have only one item, position is 1, but your list has only index 0.... use `position-1`. If this is your position in listview, keep in mind that you have an offset by scrolling.

Comment: where are you getting value of position variable from?

Comment: can you please illustrate a condition for that? I also came up in checking if the size() and the get(position) are equal then I will remove position -1?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I'll just edit my question and include full adapter.

Comment: not only for the last one, you have the off by one error in any case.

Comment: I hope you could give me some conditional statements for that so I could consider it an answer. Sorry I'm quite confused.

Comment: i didnt get the full code, but you remove an item from list `cart_list.remove(getItem(position));`and after that you try to acces it by `cart_list.get(position).getItemId()` that seams not right

Comment: Why doing this horrible thing: `cart_list.remove(getItem(position));` when you can just do: `cart_list.remove(position);`? And btw your variable should be named `cardList` to respect Java convention (or even better `mCardList` as it one of your Adapter fields). Plus you don't need to do `ArrayList<Cart_List> cart_list = new ArrayList<>();` as the `card_list` field is initialised in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by the use of the following two lines:

`cart_list.remove(getItem(position));
...
Call<Pending_Items_Model> call = service.deletePendingItem(cart_list.get(position).getItemId());`

Notifying about set won't help as you're trying to get the item on the position you just removed withing the same method. If you want to obtain that item, I would suggest refactoring to this:

`Cart_List removedCartcart_list.remove(getItem(position));
...
Call<Pending_Items_Model> call = service.deletePendingItem(removedCart.getItemId());`